# How can I run light to light first, then switch, then continue the run to more circuits?

Tags: electrical

I have a circuit that I'd like continue after a switch  like this:

Outlet → Outlet → Light → Switch (CONTINUE) → Outlet → Outlet → Outlet → Outlet → Outlet

How can I continue the run with the switch as a junction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Run a /3 cable from the light to the switch

This is easy -- you just need to run a /3 cable from the light to the switch, then use the red wire in the cable as a switched hot from the switch back to the light.

Comment: Thanks @ThreePhaseEel but how do I continue past the switch? Do I just pigtail off of the black hot? Here's a diagram of the switch loop: https://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/images/switch_loop_new.gif

Comment: @John -- yep, you run the cable to the further outlets off the always-hot and neutral in the switch box

Comment: Use black as always-hot and red for switched-hot, and the oclors will even match!

Comment: Thanks! So the dangling, unused neutral in the photo I linked above I use to continue the neutral too?

Comment: @John -- exactly